# What happens if proxy is not applied system wide in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, proxy

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, I see that there is not an option to apply system wide proxy in Network Settings. Instead, I need to edit etc/environment.

My question is what's the difference between proxy that is system wide and proxy that is set in Network Settings?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with Network Settings, the GUI program of Ubuntu?

Comment: @paladin yes, that's the one!